# how to add a sleep function in this program in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sleep

how can i implement a rest time which takes a little bit of time before doing the resa() function for each loop in my set interval.
tried with setTimeout but it continues; :(

```
 var checkInterval = setInterval(() => {
        
        if (document.documentElement.innerText.includes('TikTok') == true){
            clearInterval(checkInterval ) //To stop the loop
            var checkInterval2 = setInterval(function () {
                résa()
                if (document.documentElement.innerText.includes('Cancel') == true){
                    clearInterval(checkInterval2 )
                }
    
                
            }, 1000);
        };
        
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function resa() {
    console.log("resaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}
var iOne = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("iOne");
    if (true) {
        clearInterval(iOne);
        var iTwo = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("iTwo");
            setTimeout(resa, 3000);
            if (true) {
                clearInterval(iTwo);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}, 200);
```